# Need assistance finding file sharing cloud for android

Tags: android

I am developing an app that will take a photo and upload it to the cloud and return a url link where the file is located, so I can send the url link to users via my own sms program.

I am looking for a simple file sharing program to use with a Java Api to use.

Here is link to a few: http://alternativeto.net/software/4shared/?platform=android

I was thinking of using cx.com but does not have java api.

The second choice is sugarsynch.

I would like some input.

Comment: "Does not have a java API" is simply wrong.  The cx.com ["File API"](http://developer.cx.com/docs/File_API) is easily done with Android and Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working on Android I seriously recommend using Google Drive with the recently released Google Drive SDK: https://developers.google.com/drive/ .

All of your users will already have a Drive account with their Google account so your users won't need to sign up for a filesharing service to use your app.

Comment: google drive has two problems. 1) you can only share a link via email using the android app they have on the market.  I am assuming it is the same with the API. 2) Issue I have addressed to google their is no download button on the webpage were the image is located.  I would need this feature in the future I want to encrypt the file and user has to download the file

Comment: @user1024882 Here's the link to an image I just uploaded: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0ByTrgRAaKEK8a2dkX0VQMFMxeUk . You can definitely download it by clicking File -> Download and there's an API call for downloading too: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get .

According to the API docs when adding a file you get a response which contains a files resource which contains several links: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert and https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource . One of those links should point to the image.